# javaScript asp classic cookie keeps returning 0

Tags: cookies, asp-classic, jscript

```
 <%@ language="javascript" %>

<%
    Response.Cookies("firstname")="Alex"
%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<%
    var fname
    fname=Request.Cookies("firstname")
    Response.write("Firstname=" & fname)
%>

</body>
</html>
```

When I launch this file in the browser it keeps giving me 0. Is this because javaScript only operates on cookies on the client? Whereas, asp is a server side technology.

If so, is there a workaround using javaScript or are people forced to use another language?

Comment: Are you requesting this page from a web server that is configured to process classic ASP (.asp) pages? You can't run ASP code from the file system.

Comment: FYI, the code between ```<%``` and ```%>``` is executed on the server.

Comment: When you test the page, what (exact) address is in the URL?

Comment: http://localhost:45877/Page.asp

Comment: Ok, so you are requesting the file from a locally running server on your machine. What operating system do you have (please specify the edition as well i.e. Windows 7 **Professional**)?

Comment: Does it output `Firstname=0` or just `0`

Comment: @ Jaromanda X  just 0

Comment: Ok and do you know if you have your web server configured to run ASP?

Comment: I wonder if it's because in many languages `&` is a bitwise AND ... not sure what language your code is in though

Comment: by the way, you have no javascript in the code you posted, so the problem isn't to do with javascript at all

Comment: Let's test one more thing that I just noticed. Change `var fname` to `dim fname`. Any code in between `<%` and `%>` is VBScript not JavaScript.

Comment: I know VBScript works, by using dim, and deleting language = javascript, but is there anyway I can use this code without VBScript. And if I can't, why not?

Comment: You can make it work with JavaScript if, as the first line of code in the file you have `<%@ Language= "Javascript" %> ` which you didn't show in your post. This just wasn't popular to do at the time. If you do use this, then put the `dim` back to `var` and make sure you have that language directive at the top of the file.

Comment: Ok, the last thing we need to test is if your server is set up to actually process ASP. I'm going to post an answer, that may not be the answer, but it has a screen-shot I want you to see. Follow the steps in the **Activating & Configuring IIS for Classic ASP** section. Also, don't get **ASP.NET** confused with **ASP**, they are two different things.

Comment: Er, I'm running this stuff in WebMatrix and the browser I'm using is google chrome if that helps.

Comment: WebMatrix is a tool you can use to write the code. Chrome is the tool you use to process the response from the server. IIS (which is what I need you to check on) is the web server that actually processes the server-side code.

Comment: By the way (just curious)...Why are you using an architecture (Classic ASP) that is now 15 years old and a tool (WebMatrix) that has been discontinued for many years?

Comment: Oddly enough, I'm doing this for a job interview(long story). Recruiter literally said "learn asp" and use "www.w3schools.com" for the ASP tutorial. Probably have to crash through ASP.NET tommorow

Comment: You need to get a new recruiter. No one uses Classic ASP since .NET came out in 2002. Also, stay away from W3 Schools as well - they have outdated and sometimes flat out incorrect information. ASP.NET won't be something you can "crash through". If you are new to .NET, it will take years to know it well.

Comment: Most likely, they won't ask me to program, Since they know from my resume that I have never used ASP classic or ASP.NET. So I will probably focus on conceptual stuff more. Like for example, difference between ASP classic vs ASP.NET. However, I learn better by programming.

Comment: Just did the Virtual Directory thing. Its still giving me zero: http://localhost/EmptySite/page.asp now I'm just plain confused.

Comment: `Response.write("Firstname=" + fname)`

Comment: Lol this worked. Forgot javaScript string catenation uses '+' If you want, post this as a answer so I can upvote and whatnot

Comment: @MichaelLin again not JavaScript, it's JScript that Active Server Pages can use instead if VBScript by default, in fact any ActiveX Scripting Language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript concatenation uses + not & so:

```
Response.write("Firstname=" + fname)
```

Answer (score -1):

ASP stands for "Active **Server** Page". The code between the delimeters `<%` and `%>` execute on a web server that has been configured to process ASP code (server-side VBScript or JavaScript with the ASP Server Object Model).

You must "request" these files from a web server where the code is processed and the results of the code are injected into the page that you get in "response" from the web server.

**Activating & Configuring IIS for Classic ASP**

If you have Windows (any version since XP) Professional, you can activate the built-in Internet Information Services web server and configure it to process "Classic ASP" files (files with .asp extensions).

For example, to set up Microsoft's Internet Information Services (IIS) to process Classic ASP, go to ***Control Panel > "Programs and Features"***. From there, click the link on the left that says ***"Turn Windows Features On or Off"***.

When  the next dialog comes up, make sure to IIS enabled and to have ASP selected as seen here:

[image: Configuring Classic ASP in IIS]

**Setting up a Virtual Directory**

Then you'll have to also set up your working directory as a virtual folder on the server.  Again, to do this in IIS, navigate to ***Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager***

When the IIS Manager opens, follow [these steps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763173.aspx) to map your working directory to a virtual directory.

**Accessing Your File**

Now that your virtual directory is set up you can access your files with a path like this:

`http://localhost/<Your Virtual Directory Name>/<path within that directory to file>.asp`

Comment: @Lankymart I made the change on my iPhone - Not a problem.

Answer (score -1):

For this please use below code :

```
<%
Response.Cookies("firstname")="Alex"
%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<%
dim fname
fname=Request.Cookies("firstname")
Response.write("Firstname=" & fname)
%>

</body>
</html>
```

and it will produce output like : Firstname=Alex

Comment: The OP has already indicated (in the comments of the OP) that they are using JavaScript, so `var` is OK.

Comment: @ScottMarcus you mean JScript. Similar but not the same, JavaScript is not an ActiveX Scripting Language.